# JQuery $.ajax() post - data to call method in my Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am still quite new to JQuery and am having difficulties with using the $.ajax() function.
 I am attempting to send data to controller for processing.

Debugging the Jquery, It doesn't look the ajax is called when click on the button.

```
  function getGuestInfo() {
        var phone= $('#phone').val();
         $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/RequestForms/getGuestInfo.ajx",
            data: phone,
            cache: false,

            success: function(response){
                // we have the response
                window.alert("success"+   response); 
                $('#guestName').html(response);
                $('#address').val('');
                $('#email').val('');
                },
            });
          window.alert("Call"); 
    }
```

the button:

```
                    <input type="button" value="Call Func" onclick="getGuestInfo()"/>
```

Controller:

```
   ## @RequestMapping(value = "/getGuestInfo.ajx", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
public @ResponseBody String getGuestInfo(
    final RequestContext requestContext, @ModelAttribute Form form) { ## Do something }
```

Also, In this case should I use post or get to call the method in the Jquery function?

Comment: What do you mean by 'it doesn't look'? Have you checked your console (F12)? You don't get an alert?

Comment: Use the developer tools console in your browser, probably the network tab - and look if there is a call being made.

Comment: Yeah I did, Also I added some logging in my controller to debug it

Comment: Also I'm getting the alert

Comment: which alert, you have 2 of them.

Comment: window.alert("Call"); this one, I'm not getting the success one

Comment: Just to answer your last question: IF you are sending data, then use POST, otherwise if you are expecting data without sending any, use GET.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you are only passing a string as your data and your Controller is expecting a Form object, your server is probably returning a "Not Found" error.  I would recommend always adding the error event to your ajax calls so you can catch them.

```
error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
   // Do something here
},
```

As for passing the correct data, you'll probably want to do something like this:

```
var dataToSend = { "phone" : phone };
```

Then change your data to:

```
data: JSON.stringify(dataToSend),
```

Comment: Adding the error event, throw the error( 500 (ACT))

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (ACT)

Comment: So your server is blowing up either in the call or isn't finding the correct action in your controller and throwing a 500 error because of it.  You'll need to pass your data in so it can be transformed into a instance of your Form class.

Comment: It's working now..  My method in the controller was messed up.. passing the   final RequestContext requestContext occure one of the problem, also had to change  type: "GET", to POST.